# Condition within select_list: Only take some columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Inside a function I have a very long list of columns in a `SELECT` expression.

This function is called at various points from the front-end. However, there are two cases: In one case, I want to have all columns which that function lists in its SELECT list. In another I only want to have half of them. Which columns to fetch is determined by the function parameter `withAdditionalStuff` set in the front-end.

Of course, in both cases the columns are for all rows the same:

- `withAdditionalStuff = false` means: return columnA, columnB, columnC... for all rows
- `withAdditionalStuff = true` means it should return  columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD, columnE, columnF... for all rows.

So, what I would need is something like this:

```
SELECT many_columns_here ..... IF `withAdditionalStuff` = TRUE
THEN many_many_other_columns_here... END IF; FROM....
```

But that doesn't work.

However, if I wrap every column inside `CASE 'withAdditionalStuff' = TRUE THEN some_column END AS some_column`, of course instead of omitting the column completely, PostgreSQL always returns the column `some_column`. So, I get a lot of empty columns when calling my function setting `withAdditionalStuff` to false. Beside from that, it is very annoying to wrap dozens of column titles inside `CASE WHEN`.

Is there a way to have a conditional expression within a `SELECT` list determinating which columns to get and which to omit completely?

The function returns its result as jsonb.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.4.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. If you want a different number of columns for each row, then no that is not possible. Please [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. (_formatted_ text please, [no screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557))

Comment: I changed the wording, hoping that it's clearer now. I don't think that sample data would be of great use here, since the content of the data is not relevant.

Comment: Why don't you simply create two views? One with all columns and one with only the columns you need?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, that function does not simply fetch columns, but also does some complicated `JOIN` and `COALESCE` things of which I'm not quite sure they will work in a view. But thanks for that hint anyway!

Comment: Create a view that returns all columns and does all the joins: `create view all_columns as select a,b,c,d from ...` then create a view on top of that, that only returns some columns: `create view some_columns as select a,d from all_columns`

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other RDBMSs like MS-SQLServer, PostgreSQL requires to have the results of functions to be well defined, so you can't omit columns in the result.

One way around this is to return a JSON object instead of a normal recordset. This way you can dynamically construct a query with the specific columns you need, and return:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
  $$ SELECT to_jsonb(x) FROM (
    SELECT $$||concat_ws(',',
      CASE WHEN withAdditionalStuff THEN $$ AdditionalStuff $$ END,
      CASE WHEN withExtraStuff      THEN $$ ExtraStuff $$ END,
      ...
      )||$$
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...
    ) x $$;
```

Comment: SQL Server also requires the result of _functions_ to be "well defined". You are probably referring to stored _procedures_ that can return arbitrary results in SQL server (something you can also do in Postgres using refcursors)

Comment: Thanks. The functions returns jsonb anyway, so that's not no problem. But where inside the SELECT do I put the condition?

Comment: @cis I updated the response. Note that `concat_ws` will ignore any NULL parameters, so it is perfect for this kind of thing.